# Microsoft Incremental Linker has stopped working VS17

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, linker-errors

Recently VS17 started giving me the "Incremental Linker has stopped working" a lot, and I mean A LOT. I did not update anything (OS or VS). It started out of a sudden for no apparent reason. Most of the time I managed to change my code so it wouldn't happen.

This is my current code (it's supposed to XOR a string and return hex escaped string):

```
__inline char* EncryptString(const char* String, const char* Key)
{
    char* szEncrypted = new char[lstrlenA(String) + 1];
    memcpy(szEncrypted, String, lstrlenA(String));

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < lstrlenA(String); ++i)
        szEncrypted[i] = String[i] ^ Key[i % (sizeof(Key) / sizeof(char))];

    std::stringstream lpStream;

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < lstrlenA(szEncrypted); ++i)
    {
        char cCharInd       = szEncrypted[i];
        int32_t nCharNum    = static_cast<int32_t>(cCharInd);

        lpStream << "\\x" << 2;
    }

    std::string sHexEscaped = lpStream.str();
    lpStream.clear();

    delete[] szEncrypted;

    char* szReturn = new char[sHexEscaped.length() + 1];
    memcpy(szReturn, sHexEscaped.c_str(), sHexEscaped.length() + 1);

    return szReturn;
}
```

Is any hotfix coming? Or maybe you know what in my code caused this? (Yes, I am deleting the returned char*. Not that it has anything to do with the linker error but don't bully me because of it).
Or is anyone else experiencing this in VS17?

Comment: I would just disable incremental linking for now.

Comment: How? I don't honestly know how

Comment: It's in the linker settings in the **General** section.

Comment: Uhh it says it's already turned off, tf?

Comment: That I have not seen..

Comment: Well thanks for trying anyway

Comment: Have you tried "clean" action when it starts misbehaving?

Comment: Wish I knew what that meant

Comment: Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: @Itsenough1 In your `Solution Explorer` right click on the name of your project and select `Clean`

Comment: @KillzoneKid Thanks mate, it works. You can make it an answer if you want and I'll accept it

Comment: @Itsenough1 Glad it worked for you too. I was getting really frustrated with it. Didn't happen for awhile though since last update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thanks mate, it works. You can make it an answer if you want and I'll
>   accept it

It seems that it might be some sort of bug in VS2017. This kind of linker error happened to me even with relatively small code and something as simple as changing the output value of `std::cout` would trigger it for example. The solution seems to be to run `Clean` action on the code, which could be found in

`Solution Explorer` -> *[Right Click on the project name]* -> `Clean`